# How to send a specialized XML request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-rpc

I'm fairly new with XML...

How would I send the following XML to "https://www.exampleserver.com" ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>ContactService.add</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value><string>privateKey</string></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value><struct>
        <member><name>FirstName</name>
          <value><string>John</string></value>
        </member>
        <member><name>LastName</name>
          <value><string>Doe</string></value>
        </member>
        <member><name>Email</name>
          <value><string>there_he_go@itsjohndoe.com</string></value>
        </member>
      </struct></value>
    </param>
  </params>
  </methodCall>
```

Comment: If you know how to send any other kind of data - XML is no exception (as long as you know how to compose the XML - which you seem to). That is, either using `XmlHttpRequest` or with `jQuery.ajax` or its equivalent in _your_ favorite library. Are you using a library?

Comment: Well that is part of my problem, I've never used XMLHttpRequest extensively before. I've looked into it and I've got this as a starting point: `var NewRequest = new XMLHttpRequestMethod(); NewRequest.open("POST","exampleserver.com"); NewRequest.send(key,data);` where "key" is a predefined variable and "data" is an object array of values. (But the issue is defining the "method name" in that data.

Comment: To clarify, I'm having trouble defining the XML "methodName" as "ContactService.add" as required by the API I'm working with

Comment: Your XML seems valid as an XML. What is the required format?

Comment: It also looks like valid XML-RPC request as per the [wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC#Examples)

Comment: I wouldn't use XML-RPC at all, if you ask me. It looks like a pretty bloated format.

Comment: It absolutely is but we are constrained by the API that we send data to. They only take data in XML-RPC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **client side** scripting, you can only send the XML to the same domain as the one the web server is on, unfortunately. This is a security feature. However, you could send it to your own server and have your server send it.

To send it to your own server, you could do the following:

```
var xml = '' + 
'<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>' +
'<methodCall>' +
  '<methodName>ContactService.add</methodName>' +
  '<params>' +
  '  <param>' +
  '    <value><string>privateKey</string></value>' +
  '  </param>' +
  '  <param>' +
  '    <value><struct>' +
  '      <member><name>FirstName</name>' +
  '        <value><string>John</string></value>' +
  '      </member>' +
  '      <member><name>LastName</name>' +
  '        <value><string>Doe</string></value>' +
  '      </member>' +
  '      <member><name>Email</name>' +
  '        <value><string>there_he_go@itsjohndoe.com</string></value>' +
  '      </member>' +
  '    </struct></value>' +
  '  </param>' +
  '</params>' +
  '</methodCall>';

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","https://www.yourdomain.com/thepage",true);
xmlhttp.send(escape(xml));
```

Comment: I have written JavaScript programs that sent to different domains.  I had to configure allow-cross-origins header/settings.